# How to use django channels to stream a script output in real-time?

Tags: python, django, celery, channel

I am using django to run a python script. Ideally, I would like to redirect the shell output to a webpage and I am using django-channels to this aim.

I am trying to call a view that runs the script asynchronously (using Celery) and then returns an HttpResponse to an html page. On this html page a javascript code opens a websocket and waits for messages to come from the script task.

Currently the script runs properly in background and the websocket connection is established. I cannot see the output on the webpage, though.

views.py:

```py
def main_view(request):
    res = script_task.delay()
    client = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
    return render(request, 'run_channels.html')
```

tasks.py:

```py
@shared_task
def macch_main_chan():
    layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(layer.send)('out', {'message': 'test'})
    print('Done!')
    return HttpResponse()
```

routing.py:

```py
from . import consumers
from django.urls import path

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/outputmacch/', consumers.PushNotification, name='out'),
]
```

consumers.py:

```py
class PushNotification(WebsocketConsumer):

    http_user = True

    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text, **kwargs):

         async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(
            "out",
            {
                "text": text,
            },
        )

    def disconnect(self, message, **kwargs):
        pass
```

run_channels.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Run</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
</body>
<script>

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/outputmacch/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e)
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#log').value += (message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Currently this is the error I get:

```py
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type HttpResponse is not JSON serializable
```

Is this related to the fact that a channel layer is not serializable and cannot be used inside a celery task?

In any case, does anyone has suggestions on how to implement real-time script logging on an html webpage (preferably using this tools)?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying something similar and I get the same error.